# Why, when I connect to my Gopro with my iPhone via bluetooth (using the Gopro app) does the picture distort under high speeds/fast movements?

Tags: ios, video, bluetooth, gopro

A real issues that's been bugging me. Have tried to find a clear answer but to no avail. I know its down to data transfer speeds but still don't quite get the mechanics!

Why is it that when I connect to my Gopro (Hero5 black) from my iPhone (iPhone 6) via bluetooth does the picture distort when I make fast movements or am traveling at speed?

(To clarify - the Gopro works flawlessly as does the iPhone. The issue seems to be with bluetooth....Why? I am connecting via bluetooth via the gopro app)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the root cause is data transfer speed.

Because max bluetooth speed on Androids is ~300Kbps, on iOS ~160Kbps.

Good quality video from GoPro is typically about 1-10Mbps.
So via bluetooth you get only low quality video.

Comment: Thank you Alexey!